# HttpRequest in ASP .NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

ASP .NET WEB API's `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` will be reused in ASP.NET 5 or re-designed one will be introduced? If so, what will happen to the former?

Answer (score 1):

Generally introduced classes are synced among the versions, and, as the `HttpRequestMessage` were introduced in `.NET 4.5`, there are high chances that the class will remain in API.

Right now on the [`ASP.NET 5`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/api-reference) site on API reference page you can find [HttpMessageContent.HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.aspx), and it's is being actively used in API 2, for example, in [HttpMessageContent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagecontent.httprequestmessage.aspx).

Comment: I noticed DefaultHttpRequest class which is similar to  HttpRequestMessage at https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore/DefaultHttpRequest.cs. Confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET 5.0, the request class will be [HttpRequest](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/7be9cefc4c7671caba7d8fe538ba6a0ad308fdad/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpRequest.cs). The default implementation of this abstract class is what you have linked in your comment. My understanding is that, going forward, `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` will not be used at the server side. However, `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` can still be used at the client side, for example, with `HttpClient`.